# derivative between two probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, derivatives

Given $P(N)$, which is the power set of non-negative integers, as a sigma-field, and $B(\cdot|n, p)$ and $PP(\cdot|\lambda)$ are binomial and poisson probability measures, respectively. Compute $\frac{dB(x)}{dPP(x)}$.

**My attempt:** First, I showed that $PP\ $ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\ B$. Since they are two probability measures, they are $P(N)$-finite. Thus, by Radon-Nikodym theorem, we have:

$\frac{dB(x)}{dPP(x)} = \frac{dB(x)/d\lambda(x)}{dPP(x)/d\lambda(x)})$ $= \frac{e^{-x}x^{k-1}(k-x)/k!}{{n \choose k}x^{k-1}(1-x)^{n-1-k}(k-nx)} = \frac{e^{-x}(k-x)}{{n\choose k}(1-x)^{n-1-k}(k-nx)}$ almost everywhere w.r.t. B

**My question:** Could anyone help verify if the **ugly** result above is correct? Or did I mess up somewhere when dividing both numerators and denominators by $d\lambda(x)$?

Comment: What is $\lambda$? Counting measure?

Comment: Yes! I am not too sure on that part though...but if it holds true, the rest should be correct. Basically, need to divide both $dPP(x)$ and $dB(x)$ by the same thing, but not sure what that thing is.

Comment: So, $dPP/d\lambda$ is just the p.m.f. of a Poisson r.v.

Comment: @d.k.o.: how come? how about the denominator?

Comment: @d.k.o.: could you please help explain why $dPP/d\lambda$ is the pmf of a Poisson r.v? And what did you get for the denominator then? I am not sure if it even makes sense to divide both by the counting (or Lebesgue) measure $\lambda$

Comment: It is the "chain rule", i.e. if $\nu\ll\lambda\ll\mu$, then
$$
d\nu/d\mu=d\nu/d\lambda\times d\lambda/d\mu.
$$
However, are you sure that $PP\ll B$?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I used that rule too but I don't know how you ended up with pmf of a Poisson. And yes, because the sigma field is power set of non-negative integers and PP is Poisson probability measure, so PP(A)=0 iff A is empty set. But this means B(A)=0 as well due to def. of binomial probability measure. You don't think so? Actually the OP should be finding the reciprocal of what I wrote.

Comment: OK. Now $B\ll \lambda$ and $\lambda\ll PP$. Then the result is just the ratio of p.m.f's because $PP\ll \lambda$ and $d\lambda/dPP=(dPP/d\lambda)^{-1}$.

Comment: @d.k.o: wait a minute....shouldn't $\lambda << B$? (because $\lambda({1}) = 0$ while $B({1})= e^{-\lambda}\lambda$, which is $\neq 0$) Also, $PP<<\lambda$ is incorrect, because of the same reasoning as with $\lambda<<B$. But I cannot see why derivative of a pdf w.r.t. counting measure becomes a pmf. You have any reference here?

Comment: $\lambda(1)=0$? It's a counting measure, i.e. $\lambda(A)=|A|$

Comment: My bad;p I thought it's a Lebesgue measure;( Then you're right. But then why $dB/d\lambda$ is a p.m.f of Binomial? which variable are we taking derivatives with respect to in $B(\cdot|n,p)$?

Comment: It's not a derivative w.r.t some parameter. It's a function $f$ satisfying:
$$
B(A)=\int_A f(x)d\lambda(x)=\sum_{x\in A}f(x).
$$

Comment: I see it now!! Thanks a ton. Shouldn't the RHS be the sum of $f(x)$ for $x$ belongs to disjoint partitions of $A$ (so, sum of simple functions)??